# Why can C compile time() without its library?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, time.h

When I use the `time()` function (i.e., just randomize seed for `rand()` ) but not include the header file `time.h`, it works for C. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int i;
  srand(time(NULL));

  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("\t%d",rand()%10);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile the code above, `g++` cannot compile it since `time.h` isn't included. But `gcc` can.

```
$gcc ra.c 
$./a.out 
    4       5       2       4       8       7       3       8       9       3
$g++ ra.c 
ra.c: In function ‘int main()’:
ra.c:8:20: error: ‘time’ was not declared in this scope
 srand(time(NULL));
                ^
```

Is it related with version of gcc or just a difference between C/C++ ?

Comment: _`#include <stdlib.h>`_ IIRC `stdlib.h` doesn't guarantee to include `time.h`.

Comment: Take a look at `<stdio.h>` `<stdlib.h>`; the C++ and C versions differ because conditional macros are used there. Maybe it has something to do with that. BTW, use `<cstdlib>` and `<cstdio>` (or better the appropriate C++ headers) in C++ (if you didn't know).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should include `<time.h>` for [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) and turn on the warnings. In C,  a function with no visible prototype is assumed to return `int` (which has been deprecated since C99). So compiling with `gcc` seems fine while `g++` doesn't.

Compile with:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic-errors file.c
```

and you'll see `gcc` also complains about it.

Comment: The "implicit `int`" rule wasn't deprecated in C99, it was removed completely. Calling a function with no visible prototype is a constraint violation in C99 and later, requiring a diagnostic. (GCC does not conform to C99 by default.)

Comment: It was deprecated in the original ansi C89 spec (a holdover from pre-ansi K&R C), and removed completely in C99.

Answer (score 2):

C89/C90 (commonly, but incorrectly, referred to as "ANSI C") had an "implicit `int`" rule. If you called a function with no visible declaration, the compiler would effectively create an implicit declaration *assuming* that the function takes arguments of the types that appear in the call and returns `int`.

The `time` function takes an argument of type `time_t*` and returns a value of type `time_t`. So given a call

```
time(NULL)
```

with no visible declaration, the compiler will generate code *as if* it took an argument of the type of `NULL` (which might be `int`) and returns an `int` result. Given

```
srand(time(NULL))
```

the value returned by `time(NULL)` will then be implicitly converted from `int` to the `unsig

If `int`, `time_t`, and `time_t*` all happen to be, say, 32 bits the call is likely to work. If they're of different sizes, it's likely to behave badly. (If `NULL` is of type `void*`, it's likely that `void*` and `time_t*`, though they're incompatible, are likely to have the same representation -- but the return type is still likely to be a problem.)

The solution, of course, is *don't do that*. If you use a standard library function, *always* provide a `#include` directive for the header that declares it.